# Change wsimport binding file to point to local resource

Tags: java, maven

I am currently working in a project, where we want to automate web service client generation using Maven's jaxws-maven-plugin. Right now, web service clients are generated using the IBM RAD 8.0 internal tool for web service client generation.

This works fine, but with the increasing number of Webservices, the process becomes too slow. Though we can get the Maven plugin to generate the Java classes in the client project and use them in local development with local server, the validation of the web service fails when we try to deploy it.
That is due to the server infrastructure, where projects need to step through test, stage and production servers, being deployed further, when tests ran successully on each of the servers.

Upon deployment, the Websphere Portal Servr tries to validate the generated web service client against the WSDL definition given in the binding Java file that is generated in the package. When running the maven plugin, the following bindung is produced:

**MyProjectHttpService**

```
 static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/MyProjectWeb/sca/MyProjectExportWS?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
```

Because the generated web project needs to run on each server from the very same EAR file, we cannot change the URL in the WSDL file between the servers.

RAD's importing tool produces a binding file that uses the classloader to get the files:

**MyProjectHttpService**

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = com.my.package.portal.MyProjectHttpService.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/wsdl/project/interfaces/MyProjectExport1.wsdl");
        if (url == null) throw new MalformedURLException("/WEB-INF/wsdl/project/interfaces/MyProjectExport1.wsdl does not exist in the module.");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       ...
    }
```

In order to find a solution we went as far as writing our own Maven plugin that downloads the XSD and WSDL files and puts them in the build package, so they could be used to generate the web service client with the wsimport plugin afterwards, but using  instead of . However, this was not successull as well, as the binding file would be produced with an absolute path:

```
 static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("file:/D:/mavenworkspace/testproject/target/META-INF/wsdl/com/my/package/portal/ws/interfaces/MyProjectExport1.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
  }
```

Any help on how we can resolve the problem would be welcome. We don't really care on how we can achieve the result of having all of the XSD and WSDL file inside our jar, being referenced relatively, so the environment doesn't matter when the webserver tries to validate the web service client.

PS: Sadly, we also cannot use multiple profiles for the different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I was finally able to resolve our problem. We came onto the right track by this blogpost (and the ones linked in it): http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/12/locally-packaged-wsdl.html

We ended up with a custom solution which combines a new maven plugin and usage of the wsimport plugin. Our own plugin does some preliminary work by downloading all .wsdl and .xsd files for a given URL. I am not allowed to share the code, but I want to give some hints on how our plugin works, so that anybody in the same situation as us can hack a fitting plugin ;)

This is the build part of the pom file of the project that becomes our web service client:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl-import</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdlimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://serveraddress/MYWEBSERVICEMODULE/WEBSERVICe?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.1</target>
                <keep>true</keep>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/com/my/company/WEBSERVICEEXPORT.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>${project.build.directory}/META-INF/wsdl/com/my/company/WEBSERVICEEXPORT.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                    </configuration>
                </execution
            </executions>   
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/META-INF/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Our plugin wsdlimport is build similar to the wsimport plugin. It takes a set of WSDL files  in the  tag. Each wsdl file is downloaded and the resulting document parsed using XPath. For each XML node that is either an "xsd:import" or "xsd:include" element, the path of the schema location is extracted and the parsed for further nodes that include (other) XSD files. What you need to look out for are nodes that reference other elements that are not simple types:

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="persons" type="bons1:BOPerson">
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="names" type="xsd:string">
```

Such elements have another namespace than simple types, which are in the xsd namespace. In our case, we have custom namespaces bons1 and bons2 (I guess BO-Namespace 1 and 2) for our BOs.

The plugin is configured to place all wsdl files in the target directory in a folder "META-INF/wsdl/packagepath/"

After that, the normal wsimport plugin takes over:
We define  to point to the path "/wsdl/packagepath/" (like above, but without the META-INF). As wsdlUrl we supply the local path to the downloaded WSDL file. This generates our java implementation.

Finally, for the downloaded and generated files to work, you need to define the META-INF folder as a resource so it is bundled into the output .jar file. By defining the META-INF folder, the WSDL and XSD files will be packaged with "/wsdl" being in the root directory of the .jar. That's why we defined the  to be "/wsdl/packagepath/..." instead of "/META-INF/wsdl/packagepath/...".

I hope this helps to solve similar problems in the future.